# be always vs. always be

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Is there any difference between saying

> I'll be always using it.

or

> I'll always be using it.

?

Comment: You wouldn't say the first one. Usually adverbs go before verbs.

Comment: The former is a more archaic and non-conventional structure. It brings to mind the expression "I'll be forever yours."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always is an adverb of frequency. When it is placed in mid position, it should come after the first auxiliary verb i.e. "will". So the latter sentence "I'll always be using it" is grammatically correct.